# Array out of bounds exception for basic array

Tags: java, arrays

For some reason the size of my array is invalid and I am not sure how I should change `NextIndex` to fix this. The size should be dynamic and changing `NextIndex` to 1 doesn't help it.

```
 /**
 * Code for E7.9
 * @Michael Goedken
 */


public class DataSet
{
   // Implmentation

int nextIndex = 0;

 double[] list = new double[1];

 public static void main (String args[])
 {
      DataSet data = new DataSet(5);
      data.add(3.5);
      data.add(7.9);
      data.add(15.2);
      data.add(-7.3);

      System.out.println("Sum: " + data.getSum());
      System.out.println("Expected: 19.3");
      System.out.println("Average: " + data.getAverage());
      System.out.println("Expected: 4.825");
      System.out.println("Maximum: " + data.getMaximum());
      System.out.println("Expected: 15.2");
      System.out.println("Minimum: " + data.getMinimum());
      System.out.println("Expected: -7.3");
     }
```

Constructs an empty data set.
@param maximumNumberOfValues the maximum this data set can hold

```
   public DataSet(int maximumNumberOfValues)
   {
       double[] list = {maximumNumberOfValues};

   }
```

Adds a data value to the data set if there is room in the array.
@param value a data value

```
   public void add(double value)
   {

       list[nextIndex] = value;
       nextIndex++;

   }
```

Gets the sum of the added data.
@return sum of the data or 0 if no data has been added

```
   public double getSum()
   {
      double sum = 0;

  for (double i : list)
        sum += i;

  return sum;
       }
```

Gets the average of the added data.
@return average of the data or 0 if no data has been added

```
   public double getAverage()
   {
       double sum = 0;
       double avg = 0;

          for (double i = 0;i<list.length;i++)
              sum += i;

          avg = sum/list.length;

          return avg;
       }
```

Gets the maximum value entered.
@return maximum value of the data
NOTE: returns -Double.MAX_VALUE if no values are entered.

```
   public double getMaximum()
   {
      double max = list[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
  {
      if (list[i] > max)
      {
          max = list[i];
      }
  }

  return max;

   }
```

Gets the minimum value entered.
@return minimum value of the data
NOTE: returns Double.MAX_VALUE if no values are entered.

```
   public double getMinimum()
   {
       double min = list[0];

      for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
      {
          if (list[i] < min)
          {
              min = list[i];
          }
      }

      return min;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public DataSet(int maximumNumberOfValues) {
  double[] list = {maximumNumberOfValues}; 
}
```

Here, `list` s a local variable declaration (and only has one element), which has nothing to do with the member variable of the same name.

Also this expression `{maximumNumberOfValues}` actually means "create an array with a single element with value `maximumNumberOfValues`"

Assign a value to the member variable instead, where that value is a new array with the desired number of elements:

```
list = new double[maximumNumberOfValues];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int nextIndex = 0;

double[] list = new double[1];
```

to

```
int nextIndex = 0;

double[] list;
```

Change your constructor from

```
public DataSet(int maximumNumberOfValues)
{
    double[] list = {maximumNumberOfValues};
}
```

to

```
public DataSet(int maximumNumberOfValues)
{
    list = new double[maximumNumberOfValues];     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`double[] list = {maximumNumberOfValues};`
That's not how you create and allocate array in Java with the size of `maximumNumberOfValues`.

You should allocate it like this: `double[] list = new double[maximumNumberOfValues];`

Update: Also, `double[] list = {maximumNumberOfValues};` should be declared like this in the constructor: `list = new double[maximumNumberOfValues]`, otherwise you are declaring a local variable. You should declare `list` as `private` outside of your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your problem is.

```
int nextIndex = 0;

double[] list = new double[1];
```

I might be wrong...  but your array is always the size of 1.
And as Ervin Szaligyi said  -> you have to create the array differently